# Plot function with many conditions

Tags: plotting, functions, conditional

I'm trying to plot the two-variable function below.

`(1-4/3*d4)/(1-d-d4)`
where `0<d4<3/4` and `d4<3d` and `d+d4 <1`.

How to plot function with many conditions like this?

Comment: Look up `RegionFunction`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Plot3D[(1 - 4/3*d4)/(1 - d - d4), {d, 0, 1}, {d4, 0, 1}
, RegionFunction ->Function[{d, d4}, 0 < d4 < 3/4 && d4 < 3 d && d + d4 < 1],PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]